# watch window vs code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, casting

in my code:

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<object> y = x as IEnumerable<object>;
```

and y is null, yet in Visual Studio's watch and immediate windows it casts (2015 Professional and 2017 Community). What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a possible bug in the expression evaluator - if you check "Use the legacy expression evaluators" in the Debugging Options then the Watch window behaves correctly.

[image]

[image]